# Ошибка в вордпрессе PHP Warning: strpos() — как исправить?

Tags: php, wordpress

В логах вордпресса ошибка

```
PHP Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in /home/site/site.org/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 687
```

И из-за этого ложится сервер, показывает нагрузку на процессор.

В самом в plugin.php

```
arsort( $wp_plugin_paths );
  foreach ( $wp_plugin_paths as $dir => $realdir ) {
    if ( strpos( $file, $realdir ) === 0 ) { // строка 687
      $file = $dir . substr( $file, strlen( $realdir ) );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Сервер ложится точно не из-за этого. От предупреждений ещё никто не умирал. Если хотите исключить эти предупреждения - надо смотреть, что там у вас за пути плагинов. Наверняка symlink какие-то. Сделайте `var_dump( $wp_plugin_path )` прямо в этом файле и дополните вопрос выводом.

Comment: Если интересует конкретно этот warn, смотрите коллстек через debug_print_backtrace и откуда он идет
Нагрузку это создать не могло. ищите проблемы в плагинах. теме или настройках сервера